# How do I use django formset_factories?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to work on a django-based project/website that logs who took out our dogs last. I am very new to django so please bear with lack of knowledge in the field. I currently have my project set up so that I have models based on users/family members, the families' dogs, posts (logs of when and who took out the dogs), and actions, which is a child class that uses the dog and post models as foreign keys to see if the dogs peed and or pooped when they were taken out. The part that I am stuck on is trying to figure out how I create the post form. Since we have two dogs I need the form/post page to display a set of check boxes (for peeing and pooping actions) for each dog model that exists. While I can successfully display one action set, I run into the difficulty of trying to display the correct number of action sets and also to post the set of actions and the post itself. I have been trying to work with the formset_factory function but I am confused as to how I get it to function properly. Can anyone help? I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while and any support would be greatly appreciated.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Post(models.Model):
    walker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    issues = models.TextField(max_length = 300)

class Action(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    peed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    pooped = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import formset_factory
from dog_log_app.models import *

class Log_Form(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Post
        fields = ("issues",)

class Action_Form(forms.Form):
    peed = forms.BooleanField(initial = False, required = False)
    pooped = forms.BooleanField(initial = False, required = False)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import formset_factory, modelformset_factory
from .models import Post, Dog, Action
from dog_log_app.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-time_posted'),
        'actions': Action.objects.all(),
        'dogs': Dog.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'dog_log_app/home.html', context)

def post(request):
    form_post = Log_Form(request.POST or None)
    form_actions = modelformset_factory(Action, fields = ('peed', 'pooped'), extra = Dog.objects.count())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_post = Log_Form(request.POST)


        if form_post.is_valid() and form_actions.is_valid():
            post_save = form_post.save(commit = False)
            post_save.walker = request.user
            post_save.save()
            form_actions.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
    
    context = {
        'post': form_post,
        'action': formset_factory(Action_Form, extra = Dog.objects.count()),
        'dogs': Dog.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'dog_log_app/post_form.html', context)
```

post_form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Create Post</legend>
                <h3>{{dogs.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{action.as_p}}</p>
                <p>{{post.as_p}}</p>
            </fieldset>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" value="Ok">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can try would be to use ajax to add the amount you want, what I usually do is use the form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'issues',
        )

class ActionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = (
            'peed', 'pooped'
        )

ActionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Post, Action, form=ActionForm,
    fields = ['peed', 'pooped'], extra=1, can_delete=True,
)
```

With the forms created, we move on to the views, which will be class-based for convenience:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm, ActionFormSet

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'your template'
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('your url')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = ActionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['formset'] = ActionFormSet()

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = self.object
                formset.instance.walker = self.request.user
                formset.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'your template'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('your url')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = ActionFormSet(
                self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['formset'] = ActionFormSet(instance=self.object)

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = self.object
                formset.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and to display the information you can use a jquery library for the dynamic information on saving:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset)
With that the configuration is much easier

An example template would be:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2>Agregar Proyecto</h2>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form id="form-container" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        <h2>Actions</h2>
                        <table>
                            {{ formset.management_form }}
                            {% for form in formset %}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                {% endif %}
                                <tr id="projects_data">
                                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                        <td>
                                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                                    {{ hidden }}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                            {{ field }}
                                        </td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ message }}</button>
                        <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#projects_data').formset({
                prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
                addText: 'create',
                deleteText: 'remove',
            });
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and in that way add data dynamically.